# What size are these mosaics of Justinian and Theodora?

Tags: art, byzantine-empire

How large are the mosaics of Justinian and Theodora in [the Basilica of San Vitale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_San_Vitale)?

I've looked in plenty of academic papers, and can't seem to find one where their size is quoted - I also do not speak Italian, and a great deal of papers about them are in Italian.

Here's a picture of the two mosaics:
[image: 1] [image: mosaic of Justin and Theodora]

Comment: Distance measuring tools embedded into [Google Maps](http://www.google.com/maps/@44.4205,12.1965,20z) show its [apse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apse) to be about [eight meters across](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter); a [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iJFqQmcV9Q&t=34s) video of its interior show each mosaic to be about a quarter of its semi-circumference. Both the above-posted pictures, as well as the afore-linked video, show their [aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) to be about two to three; thus, it would appear they are life-sized.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to The Met Museum website, the mosaic *[Emperor Justinian and Members of His Court](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/466586)* measures **104 in. by 144 in. or 264.2cm by 365.8cm, which is 8ft 8in by 12ft**. The same dimensions are given for the mosaic *[Empress Theodora and Members of Her Court](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/466587)*.

Slightly less precise measurements of **8ft 8in by 12ft, or 2m 64cm by 3m 65cm** are given in [this source](https://lmcarthur.weebly.com/uploads/4/9/0/0/4900041/chapter_7-2.pdf) for both mosaics.

A third source, *[Imperial Gifts](https://www.baylor.edu/content/services/document.php/253565.pdf)*, has both mosaics measure slightly smaller at **8ft 6in by 12ft, or 2m 59cm by 3m 65cm**.

As can be seen in the image below, the mosaics face each other in the church's apse. They date to approximately 547 AD. More details can be found on The Met's *[Dress Styles in the Mosaics of San Vitale](https://www.metmuseum.org/exhibitions/listings/2012/byzantium-and-islam/blog/topical-essays/posts/san-vitale)* which also notes that:

> In both portraits, the rulers are dressed to identify themselves with
> the saints and prophets surrounding them in mosaic decoration, and to
> establish their eternal presence among the divine.

[image]

*The apse of San Vitale showing the two mosaics on either side of the three windows, with Justinian on the left and Theodora on the right. As suggested by* Lucian *in a comment above, the people portrayed appear to life-size. Image source: [akg images](https://www.akg-images.com/archive/-2UMDHUN1G65R.html)*